# Indefinite integral $\int \sqrt{(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})(e^{2x}-e^{-2x}+4) }\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> The goal is to integrate $$\int \sqrt{(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})(e^{2x}-e^{-2x}+4) } dx$$

My approach would be to factorize the expression beneath the square root and then take the squareroot of that. However I fail to do this.

What approach is suitable and how would you do it?

Comment: Are you sure it is $e^{-2}$ not $e^{-2x}$?

Comment: you're correct.

Comment: and the title...

Comment: So, $\cosh x =(e^x+e^{-x})/2$ and  $\sinh x =(e^x-e^{-x})/2$

Comment: @TylerHG yes? I've noticed that connection.

Comment: This has no closed form according to *Mathematica*.

Comment: I was a simplification of $2\pi \int \sinh(x) \sqrt{1 + Dsinh(x)^2} dx$

Comment: After substituting $t=e^{2x}$, and using FullSimplify[...], *Mathematica* is able to return a result in terms of various [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).